# How should I select a battery solution for my project? (24 V/150 mAh with recharging)

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging

I'm designing my first ever electrical project and have questions about selecting an appropriate battery solution. I'll put the requirements up front.

- Max power draw - 24 V @ 150 mA
- Average power draw - 24 V @ 55 mA
- Rechargeable solution, ideally in situ through USB plugin or similar
- Portable in that it can be reasonably hand-held, ruling out some larger straight 24 V batteries
- Ideally a few hours of run time

I've attempted to do some reading and research on what may be best, but I've not really found an "ideal" solution. Most 24 V batteries I've seen are designed for larger solutions (i.e. car battery style things). I was originally thinking of leveraging something like a USB power bank, but research suggests I shouldn't be using a DC converter higher than a 3:1 ratio (so I wouldn't want to go more than 15 V output).

I imagine the ultimate solution may involve lots of AAs in series of similar, but I'm not sure how to easily turn this into an "in situ" rechargeable solution.

I apologize that this is most likely a very basic question, and I'm sure variants are repeated often on this exchange. I did look through other answers and searches but nothing really seemed to match a solution with my requirements.

Comment: I suppose the unit in the first two points really should be mA rather than mAh. How much leeway do you have regarding the voltage? The voltage will drop as the battery is discharged, especially so for lithium chemistries.

Comment: What precisely does this mean --> *Max Power Draw - 24v @ 150mAh*

Comment: polwel - You are correct, I apologize, mA, not mAh. Honestly I'm not sure what tolerances would be acceptable, it's a device which simply say's 24v input.  


Andyaka - It's a sensor and when it detects data the power draw peeks, but otherwise it will be sitting at the average power draw in standby

Comment: 5V -->BOOST-->12V_battery -->BOOST--> DEVICE

Comment: So what is your expected run time? That will define the size of battery you need when you calculate with the energy use.

Comment: Your title says 150 mAh. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I see several solutions but more information is needed. I will take a SWAG Assuming the 24V is not critical you could use two small SLA batteries in series, I have seen then as small as about 12 V 1 Ah. The side will be determined by your run time. The range would be from about 22 V (flat) to about 30 V (charging). If the voltage is critical you could use a SEPIC converter to maintain the 24 V for you regardless of the charge(ing) voltage. The charger becomes a much simpler device. Many of the USB boost converters can be used to charge the battery. The ones I had allow separate adjustment for voltage and current. SLA you charge with a constant current then float at about 13 V, check the battery data sheet for the correct value.